# bind interface by different concrete class in hilt?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt .
I have one interface but I have two classes that have implemented them.
I need @Bind interface by different implemented in ViewModels .
pleas help me ?
create custom Component? or use custom Scope ?

Answer (score 9):

A given code from you would help, but lets assume this:

### Your Interface

```
interface YourInterface {}
```

### Classes

```
class MyFirstClassImpl @Inject constructor() : YourInterface

class MySecondClassImpl @Inject constructor() : YourInterface
```

### Di Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
inteface YourClassModule {
    @Binds
    @MyFirstClass
    fun provideMyFirstClass(class: MyFirstClassImpl): YourInterface

    @Binds
    @MySecondClass
    fun provideMySecondClass(class: MySecondClassImpl): YourInterface

}

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyFirstClass

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MySecondClass
```

### ViewModel

```
class YourViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @MyFirstClass private val firstClass: YourInterface,
    @MySecondClass private val secondClass: YourInterface
) : ViewModel()
```

This should do the job.

Comment: What is the need for `@MyFirstClass` and `@MySecondClass` annotations? Is it only there for readability?

Comment: No, it is not. Because, MyFirstClass and MySecondClass provide the same Interface, you have to tell hilt, how to differentiate from them. Without `@MyFirstClass` and  `@MySecondClass`, hilt would NOT know, when to provide which class.

Comment: @Andrew, How do you use Binds, when an activity implements the interface and with the callback received, you want to do some business logic in Activity? Please help!

Comment: @Rakesh You can't. The Activity has to inherit from the Interface callback and then do something inside the callback.

Comment: @Andrew, Could you please provide an example for better understanding?

Comment: @Rakesh Please open a new issue for this, because your question has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Andrew, I opened a new question. Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257684/how-to-bind-external-library-class-with-callback-in-hilt

Comment: @Andrew Could you please help!