# How to Choose Specific Concrete Implementation of Interface with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, dependency-inversion

Let's say I have an application using Dagger Hilt and a view model that wants to inject an interface type that has multiple concrete implementations. How can I provide the correct concrete implementation without explicitly stating that I was trying to? (If there is an answer, I'd appreciate a base Dagger response too.)

In my eyes, an example of explicitly stating which concrete implementation to provide would be using the @Named annotation.

In my personal opinion, explicitly stating which implementation I need like this is a violation of the Dependency Inversion principle. In my case, the view model (and dev by extension) should only have knowledge of the interface type, not of its concrete implementations.

Perhaps using conditional statements in the provide function (in the module for supplying the interface) is the best solution, but I'm hesitant to believe that is true. For one, it looks like a hack, and, two, Dagger Hilt has been out for around 3 years so there must be a better way by now, right?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why [Hilt modules](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#hilt-modules) cannot handle this adequately for your use case?

Comment: Are you talking about using the `@Qualifier` annotation? This would violate the dependency inversion principle I talk about in my example.
Also, one limitation of the `@Qualifier` annotation, unrelated to my question, is that the view model must know what implementation it needs at compile time, but isn't allowed to change the concrete implementation during run time. I suppose a design pattern would suffice, but it's something I'd like to point out from this post I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367053/dagger-hilt-with-multiple-implementations-of-an-interface